# invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""

Tags: postgresql, numeric

```
SELECT Concat(npi.first_name, ' ', npi.middle_name, ' ', npi.last_name) AS othername, npi.nhif_persons_identity_serial,
  CASE WHEN npi.person_identity_number IS NULL THEN '' WHEN Trim(npi.person_identity_number) = '' THEN ''
    ELSE npi.contact_email END, npi.biometric_member_number, npi.birth_certificate_number, npi.national_id_number, CASE
    WHEN npi.national_passport_number IS NULL THEN '' WHEN Trim(npi.national_passport_number) = '' THEN ''
    ELSE npi.national_passport_number END, CASE WHEN npi.national_pin_number IS NULL THEN ''
    WHEN Trim(npi.national_pin_number) = '' THEN '' ELSE npi.national_pin_number END, CASE
    WHEN npi.contact_email IS NULL THEN '' WHEN Trim(npi.contact_email) = '' THEN '' ELSE npi.contact_email END, CASE
    WHEN npi.address_district IS NULL THEN '' WHEN Trim(npi.address_district) = '' THEN '' ELSE npi.address_district
  END, CASE WHEN npi.address_location IS NULL THEN '' WHEN Trim(npi.address_location) = '' THEN ''
    ELSE npi.address_location END, CASE WHEN npi.address_county IS NULL THEN ''
    WHEN Trim(npi.address_county) = '' THEN '' ELSE npi.address_county END, CASE WHEN npi.work_code IS NULL THEN ''
    WHEN Trim(npi.work_code) = '' THEN '' ELSE npi.work_code END, CASE WHEN npi.address_physical IS NULL THEN ''
    WHEN Trim(npi.address_physical) = '' THEN '' ELSE npi.address_physical
  END
  , npi.date_of_birth  , npi.date_registered, npi.date_added,CASE WHEN npi.gender IS NULL THEN ''
    WHEN Trim(npi.gender) = '' THEN '' ELSE npi.gender
  END
  , npi.first_name, npi.middle_name, npi.last_name,

   CASE WHEN npi.marital_status IS NULL THEN ''
    WHEN Trim(npi.marital_status) = '' THEN '' ELSE npi.marital_status
  END
  ,CASE WHEN npi.contact_address IS NULL THEN ''
    WHEN Trim(npi.contact_address) = '' THEN '' ELSE npi.contact_address
  END
  ,CASE WHEN npi.contact_telephone IS NULL THEN ''
    WHEN Trim(npi.contact_telephone) = '' THEN '' ELSE npi.contact_telephone
  END
  ,CASE WHEN npi.contact_mobile IS NULL THEN ''
    WHEN Trim(npi.contact_mobile) = '' THEN '' ELSE npi.contact_mobile
  END
  ,CASE WHEN npi.mobile_contact_detail IS NULL THEN ''
    WHEN Trim(npi.mobile_contact_detail) = '' THEN '' ELSE npi.mobile_contact_detail
  END
  ,CASE WHEN npi.temp_member_number IS NULL THEN ''
     ELSE npi.temp_member_number
  END
  ,CASE WHEN npi.national_nhif_number IS NULL THEN ''
    WHEN Trim(npi.national_nhif_number) = '' THEN '' ELSE npi.national_nhif_number
  END
  ,CASE WHEN nbci.facial_full_image IS NULL THEN ''
    WHEN Trim(nbci.facial_full_image) = '' THEN '' ELSE nbci.facial_full_image
  END
  ,CASE WHEN nbci.facial_scaled_image IS NULL THEN ''
    WHEN Trim(nbci.facial_scaled_image) = '' THEN '' ELSE nbci.facial_scaled_image
  END

FROM nhif_persons_identities npi
  INNER JOIN nhif_biometric_cards nbc ON npi.nhif_persons_identity_serial = nbc.nhif_persons_identity_serial
  INNER JOIN nhif_biometric_card_images nbci ON nbci.nhif_biometric_card_serial = nbc.nhif_biometric_card_serial
WHERE npi.nhif_persons_identity_serial = 293182
```

Am selecting data from database and if the column doesn't contain any value it output "blank" , Though am running into the error below when i execute the query i have tried to search but the answers i have got doesn't work.
It seems its the error with numeric.

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
> LINE 35:   ,CASE WHEN npi.temp_member_number IS NULL THEN ''
>                                                           ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
> SQL state: 22P02
> Character: 2318
> ```

Comment: The error message is quit clear: you’re trying to use an empty string as a number. That doesn’t work. All values in a case must be the same type.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you try to get text, not integer, so you would see euther some number like `1234` or empty string ``, not zero, to do that cast `numeric` to text, eg:

`ELSE npi.temp_member_number::text`

then you get the wanter result...

(apply to all not text fields, where you expect empty string if `NULL`)